# How can I return data from a MySQL query without it being [Object, object] and also, not a string via JSON.stringify?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json

I am getting the following results from SELECT query to a table in a MySQL db:

```
[
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    title: 'foo',
    date: 2012-07-06T08:40:14.000Z
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 2,
    title: 'foo',
    date: 2021-12-16T16:00:12.000Z
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 3,
    title: 'foo',
    date: 2012-07-06T08:40:14.000Z
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 4,
    title: 'foo',
    date: 2019-12-02T14:13:41.000Z
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 5,
    title: 'foo',
    date: 2019-11-25T12:46:25.000Z
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 6,
    title: 'foo',
    date: 2021-12-17T16:00:12.000Z
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 7,
    title: 'foo',
    date: 2021-12-15T16:00:12.000Z
  }
]
```

How can I return this within a response to an API call without it being returned as [object, object]?

I want to return it without it being a string as a string isn't that useable compared to JSON.

Comment: try returning `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))`

Comment: @Kinglish This has worked but only if called from the top level function without abstraction. Thank you.